# Preventing food from generating inside my snake

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me how I can make it so the food doesn't generate inside my snake? I've tried using a `for` loop that checks every index of the snake to see if it's matching with the position of the food but this still doesn't work.

Also, I sped up the speed of the game and the amount of units that are added to the snake upon eating a food to speed up the results and to check and see if the method actually works.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{x: cvsW/2, y: cvsH/2}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 //set direction
 if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
 //refresh canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 //draw snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
 }

 //grab head position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //posistion food on board
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //send the snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 // //check if snake hit wall
 // if(headX < 0 || headY < 0 || headX > (cvsW-unit) || headY > (cvsH-unit)) {
 //  clearInterval(runGame);
 // }

 if (headX < 0) headX = cvsW - unit;
 else if (headX > cvsW - unit) headX = 0;
 else if (headY < 0) headY = cvsH - unit;
 else if(headY > cvsH - unit) headY = 0;

 // for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
 //  if(headX == snake[i].x && headY == snake[i].y) {
 //   clearInterval(game);
 //  }
 // }

 //create new head
 let newHead = {x: headX, y: headY}

 //if snake eats food -do this
 if(headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
  //create new food position
  while(!checkSnakeForFood()) {
    food = {
    x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
    y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
   }
  }
  
  //add 3 units to the snake
  for (let i = 30; i > 0; i--) {
   snake.unshift(newHead);
  }
 }
 else {
  //remove tail
  snake.pop();
 }

 //add head to snake
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 40);

function checkSnakeForFood() {
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  if(snake[i].x === food.x && snake[i].y === food.y) return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that would be better, thanks:) any idea on how to make it so the food doesn't generate inside the snake

Comment: Sure--you have the right idea, but when you run into a collision between the tail and the food and you randomly re-place the food again, there's no guarantee you won't plop it onto another segment of the tail that you've already checked. Try this algorithm: `while (!checkFoodValidity()) { placeFoodRandomly(); }`.

Comment: oh lol my bad, thanks for the help I'll try it out

Comment: This had some unexpected results the food is now not generating to a different spot     http://jsfiddle.net/L10mh8ey/1/

Comment: @ggorlen ok took me a min but check it out

Comment: Thanks. Looks good--did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: No, I'm just having trouble understanding. I'm a slow learner and really need things kind of spelled out for me step by step, sorry you put all that effort into it.

Comment: No problem. What part isn't making sense?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `checkSnakeForFood()` doesn't work as you expect because `newHead` hasn't yet been added to the snake body by the time you test for food-head collision.

Only the snake tail is checked and the `checkSnakeForFood()` routine reports that the current food placement (right underneath `newHead`) is not a collision, so the `while` loop body is not executed and the food doesn't move. Here's a diagram of what's happening:

```
 0123456789
0+--------- 
1|.........
2|.F######.
3|.......##
    ^^^^^^^
       |
only these segments get
tested for collision
```

`newHead` and `food` have the same location, `[2, 2]`, denoted by the `F`. They're colliding, so `if (headX == food.x && headY == food.y)` is true. However, when `checkSnakeForFood()` is called on the next line, only the tail `#` elements are taken into consideration in the loop `for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++)`. `checkSnakeForFood()` then returns true and the `while` loop never repositions the food.

You can resolve this issue by `unshift`ing the `newHead` before attempting to call `checkSnakeForFood()` as follows:

```
  //create new head
  let newHead = {
    x: headX,
    y: headY
  }

  //add head to snake, *before* checking for collision with the food
  snake.unshift(newHead);

  //if snake eats food -do this
  if (headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
    //create new food position
    while (!checkSnakeForFood()) {  // <-- now this will successfully detect
                                    // that the snake head is touching the food
```

Now, the food-head collision will register correctly, and the food will be repositioned until it doesn't collide with the snake's tail *or* head:

```
 0123456789
0+--------- 
1|.........
2|.F######.
3|.......##
   ^^^^^^^^
       |
all segments are correctly
tested for collision
```

However, I recommend a refactor to help avoid bugs like this. You can make `snake` an object with member functions for collision and movement and properties for its `direction` and `tail`. Your `draw` function is very overburdened and is responsible for a lot more than its name promises.

Detaching `newHead` seems like an error-prone approach; manipulating the head directly on the array will save you a lot of confusion.

In the meantime, here's the updated code to get you moving again (remember to click the `Full page` link in the snippet to play the game properly:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{
  x: cvsW / 2,
  y: cvsH / 2
}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
  x: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsW / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit,
  y: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsH / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
  //set direction
  if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
  else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
  else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
  else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
  //refresh canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
  //draw snake
  for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
    ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
  }

  //grab head position
  let headX = snake[0].x;
  let headY = snake[0].y;

  //posistion food on board
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

  //send the snake in chosen direction
  if (direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
  else if (direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
  else if (direction == 'right') headX += unit;
  else if (direction == 'down') headY += unit;

  // //check if snake hit wall
  // if(headX < 0 || headY < 0 || headX > (cvsW-unit) || headY > (cvsH-unit)) {
  //  clearInterval(runGame);
  // }

  if (headX < 0) headX = cvsW - unit;
  else if (headX > cvsW - unit) headX = 0;
  else if (headY < 0) headY = cvsH - unit;
  else if (headY > cvsH - unit) headY = 0;

  // for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  //  if(headX == snake[i].x && headY == snake[i].y) {
  //   clearInterval(game);
  //  }
  // }

  //create new head
  let newHead = {
    x: headX,
    y: headY
  }

  //add head to snake
  snake.unshift(newHead);

  //if snake eats food -do this
  if (headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
    //create new food position
    while (!checkSnakeForFood()) {
      food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsW / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsH / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit
      }
    }

    //add 3 units to the snake
    for (let i = 30; i > 0; i--) {
      snake.unshift(newHead);
    }
  } else {
    //remove tail
    snake.pop();
  }
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 40);

function checkSnakeForFood() {
  for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    if (snake[i].x === food.x && snake[i].y === food.y) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

canvas {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your food draw into a for loop + if statement:

```
var foodNotPlaced;

snake.forEach(function(segment) {
    if (food.x != segment.x and food.y != segment.y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);
    foodNotPlaced = false;
    }
    else {
    food.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit;
    food.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit;
    foodNotPlaced = True;
});
```

Then rerun inside of a while loop to make sure the food gets placed before the rest of your code runs

```
while foodNotPlaced {
snake.forEach(function(segment) {
    if (food.x != segment.x and food.y != segment.y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);
    foodIsPlaced = false;
    }
    else {
    food.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit;
    food.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit;
    foodIsPlaced = true;
});
}
```