# How to make sure food isn't placed inside snake?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Javascipt snake game and was wondering Can I get a detailed explanation, step by step on how to make sure the food item is not generated inside the snake? I've been given some answers but I can't really understand them. I know I need to use a while loop somewhere but I'm clueless on the function. Thanks:)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{x: cvsW/2, y: cvsH/2}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 //set direction
 if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
 //refresh canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 //draw snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
 }

 //grab head position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //posistion food on board
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //send the snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 // //check if snake hit wall
 // if(headX < 0 || headY < 0 || headX > (cvsW-unit) || headY > (cvsH-unit)) {
 //  clearInterval(runGame);
 // }

 if (headX < 0) headX = cvsW - unit;
 else if (headX > cvsW - unit) headX = 0;
 else if (headY < 0) headY = cvsH - unit;
 else if(headY > cvsH - unit) headY = 0;

 // check to see if snake has collided with itself
 // for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
 //  if(headX == snake[i].x && headY == snake[i].y) {
 //   clearInterval(game);
 //  }
 // }

 //create new head
 let newHead = {x: headX, y: headY}

 //if snake eats food -do this
 if(headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
  //create new food position
   food = {
   x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
   y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
  }
  
  //add 3 units to the snake
  for (let i = 30; i > 0; i--) {
   snake.unshift(newHead);
  }
 }
 else {
  //remove tail
  snake.pop();
 }

 //add head to snake
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 40);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've posted this question [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263835/how-can-i-make-it-so-the-food-doesnt-generate-inside-my-snake) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186910/food-unit-doesnt-generate-a-new-location-in-my-js-snake-game) now under different accounts. That's pretty frustrating--I posted a [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54264201/6243352) for you to this exact question yesterday.

Comment: @ggorlen sorry man I didn't understand your answer and did'nt want to keep wasting your time. I've posted on other sites besides SO and still wasn't understanding it. Thought if someone else tried to explain it, maybe it would click.

Comment: Spamming the same question 3 times under different accounts is not what this site is about. I changed one line of code in my answer--can you explain what about that change you aren't understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can `.map` the snake's current coordinates to an array of strings `currentSnakeX_Ys` (`x#_y#`), then generate `food` `x` and `y`s while `` currentSnakeX_Ys.includes(`${food.x}_${food.y}`) ``:

```
//create new food position
const currentSnakeX_Ys = snake.map(({ x, y }) => `${x}_${y}`);
do {
  food = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsW / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsH / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit
  }
} while (currentSnakeX_Ys.includes(`${food.x}_${food.y}`));
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{
  x: cvsW / 2,
  y: cvsH / 2
}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
  x: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsW / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit,
  y: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsH / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
  //set direction
  if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
  else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
  else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
  else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
  //refresh canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
  //draw snake
  for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
    ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
  }

  //grab head position
  let headX = snake[0].x;
  let headY = snake[0].y;

  //posistion food on board
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

  //send the snake in chosen direction
  if (direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
  else if (direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
  else if (direction == 'right') headX += unit;
  else if (direction == 'down') headY += unit;

  // //check if snake hit wall
  // if(headX < 0 || headY < 0 || headX > (cvsW-unit) || headY > (cvsH-unit)) {
  //  clearInterval(runGame);
  // }

  if (headX < 0) headX = cvsW - unit;
  else if (headX > cvsW - unit) headX = 0;
  else if (headY < 0) headY = cvsH - unit;
  else if (headY > cvsH - unit) headY = 0;

  // check to see if snake has collided with itself
  // for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  //  if(headX == snake[i].x && headY == snake[i].y) {
  //   clearInterval(game);
  //  }
  // }

  //create new head
  let newHead = {
    x: headX,
    y: headY
  }

  //if snake eats food -do this
  if (headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
    //create new food position
    const currentSnakeX_Ys = snake.map(({ x, y }) => `${x}_${y}`);
    do {
      food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsW / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsH / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit
      }
    } while (currentSnakeX_Ys.includes(`${food.x}_${food.y}`));

    //add 3 units to the snake
    for (let i = 30; i > 0; i--) {
      snake.unshift(newHead);
    }
  } else {
    //remove tail
    snake.pop();
  }

  //add head to snake
  snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 40);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Snake Game</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    canvas {
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 750px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

(you could also iterate through the `snake` instead after every food generation, and check that the current `x` and `y` are nto both the food's `x` and `y`, but creating an array of strings in advance makes things far easier because then you can just use an `.includes` test)

To keep the code DRY, rather than typing this out every time you need to generate food, put the above into a function, and call that function:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{
  x: cvsW / 2,
  y: cvsH / 2
}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

function makeFood() {
  //create new food position
  let newFood;
  const currentSnakeX_Ys = snake.map(({ x, y }) => `${x}_${y}`);
  do {
    newFood = {
      x: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsW / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit,
      y: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((cvsH / unit) - 1) + 1) * unit
    }
  } while (currentSnakeX_Ys.includes(`${newFood.x}_${newFood.y}`));
  return newFood;
}
   
//create food object
let food = makeFood();

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
  //set direction
  if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
  else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
  else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
  else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
  //refresh canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
  //draw snake
  for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
    ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
  }

  //grab head position
  let headX = snake[0].x;
  let headY = snake[0].y;

  //posistion food on board
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

  //send the snake in chosen direction
  if (direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
  else if (direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
  else if (direction == 'right') headX += unit;
  else if (direction == 'down') headY += unit;

  // //check if snake hit wall
  // if(headX < 0 || headY < 0 || headX > (cvsW-unit) || headY > (cvsH-unit)) {
  //  clearInterval(runGame);
  // }

  if (headX < 0) headX = cvsW - unit;
  else if (headX > cvsW - unit) headX = 0;
  else if (headY < 0) headY = cvsH - unit;
  else if (headY > cvsH - unit) headY = 0;

  // check to see if snake has collided with itself
  // for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  //  if(headX == snake[i].x && headY == snake[i].y) {
  //   clearInterval(game);
  //  }
  // }

  //create new head
  let newHead = {
    x: headX,
    y: headY
  }

  //if snake eats food -do this
  if (headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
    food = makeFood();

    //add 3 units to the snake
    for (let i = 30; i > 0; i--) {
      snake.unshift(newHead);
    }
  } else {
    //remove tail
    snake.pop();
  }

  //add head to snake
  snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 40);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Snake Game</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    canvas {
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 750px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a function that generates a random point for food like this

```js
function getFood() {
  // get a random point
  let food = {
    x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
    y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
  }
  // check if this point is in the snake
  // loop through each point of the snake
  for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    // check if the current snake point equals the generated point
    if(snake[i].x == point.x && snake[i].y == point.x)
      // stop the loop and return getFood() to generate an other point
      return getFood()
  }
  return food
}
```

and just call getFood() whenever you want to get a food position that isn't inside the snake

```js
food = getFood()
```